# NET Core 3.1 EF migration from compiled portable library in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I doing development process in Windows, but I want to upload to remote Linux hosting only compiled library (without any source code). My library contains:

1. ApplicationDbContext
2. Last migration DB structure
3. Config file with definition of connection string.
4. Useful attributes

> ```
> <DbContext(GetType(ApplicationDbContext))>
> <Migration("20200624210431_MySqlStart")>
> ```

Locally (in windows) I upload this migration to DB engine successfully by "**Update-database**" in VS Package manager console.
I try to use various command like "**dotnet ef database update --project XXX --context YYY**" and other, but any my attempt to deploy DB in hosting from compiled library has been failured for various reason.
What right way to solve this simple task?